# Combinations of marbles

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say I have 10 marbles, with a known distribution. Just as an example, I have the following, but I'm trying to find a general solution.

- Red- 5
- Blue- 2
- Green- 3

I draw 5 without replacement from the bag. How can I determine the number of combinations possible that will be drawn?

Comment: Just branch out the possibilities. all 5 red; 4 red and ..; 3 red and ....; etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use generating functions. I.e., in your case for:
\begin{align}
\text{Red:}   & 1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4 + z^5 \\
\text{Blue:}  & 1 + z + z^2 \\
\text{Green:} & 1 + z + z^2 + z^3
\end{align}
Then the generating function of the number of posibilities is just:
$$
(1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4 + z^5) \cdot (1 + z + z^2) \cdot (1 + z + z^2 + z^3)
$$
Some simplifications are possible. This is:
\begin{align}
\frac{(1 - z^6) (1 - z^3) (1 - z)^4)}{(1 - z)^3}
  &= (1 - z^2 - z^3 + z^5 - z^6 + z^8 + z^9 - z^{11}) 
       \cdot \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{-3}{k} z^k \\
  &= (1 - z^2 - z^3 + z^5 - z^6 + z^8 + z^9 - z^{11}) 
       \cdot \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{k + 2}{2} z^k
\end{align}
The ways to take 5 marbles are the coefficient of $z^5$ in this, a combination of binomial coefficients.

No simple formulas, sorry.